# Given a DP problem, how can I prove it is equivalent to some other DP problem?

Tags: algorithm, dynamic-programming

Here I have a DP problem (say Problem 1)and I think it is equivalent to some other DP problem (say Problem 2). How can I prove formally that these are indeed equivalent and not just a hunch.

[Problem 1 is "rock-bashing"](https://leetcode.com/problems/last-stone-weight-ii/) where you start with a set of rocks each with sizes, and you repeatedly choose two rocks, bash them together, which results in the destruction of them both if they are the same size, or results in a smaller rock of size a-b if a is the size of the larger rock and b the smaller. You repeat until there's a single rock. The problem is to find a sequence of rock-bashings that results in the smallest possible remaining rock.

Problem 2 is to divide array into two subsets such that difference between the two subsets is minimum.

How can I prove that these two problems are equivalent? Is induction the way but I am not able to think of a structure to prove the equivalence through induction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering the specific part of your question: how to prove equivalence between "rock-bashing" and "minimise partition difference".

If you've got a solution to the "rock bashing" problem, then you have a sequence of bashes of stones. You can turn this into a partition of the rocks into two sets where the difference between the sizes of the partitions is the value of the final rock as follows:

Write the size of each rock on each rock. When you bash together two rocks, and the larger has "E" written on it, and the smaller "F", then write "(E - F)" on the remaining piece of the larger rock and discard the smaller rock. (If the two rocks are of equal size, write "(E-F)" on one of the now zero-sized pieces of rock, and discard the other).

At the end, you have one rock left. Expand all the brackets out, and put the rock sizes of positive size in set A, and the rock sizes of negative size in set B.

For example, if you have rocks of size 7, 5, 4, you start with:

```
rock{size=7, text="7"}
rock{size=5, text="5"}
rock{size=4, text="4"}
```

Suppose you bash 5 and 4 together, you now have:

```
rock{size=1, text="(5-4)"}
rock{size=7, text="7"}
```

Now you bash the smaller fragment against the 7 rock, leaving:

```
rock{size=7, text="(7-(5-4))"}
```

Expand the brackets of "(7-(5-4))" to get "7 - 5 + 4", so this corresponds to a partition {7, 4} (the positive numbers), and {5} (the negative numbers). The sum-difference between these two partitions is 6, the same as the size of the final rock. (Note, this isn't an optimal partition or rock-bashing).

Easier is the other direction of the proof: partitions translate to rock-bashings.

If you have a partition into two sets A and B, take an element a in A and an element b in B, and if a>=b, replace a with a-b in A and remove b from B. Otherwise, remove a from A and replace b with "b-a". This can repeat until there's only one element left. Note that this procedure preserves sum(A) - sum(B), ie the partition difference. And also note that this corresponds exactly to a rock-bashing resulting in the (absolute value of the) partition difference.

This shows that we can match partitions with sum-difference d and rock-bashings resulting in a rock of size d.

Thus we can solve either problem to find the optimal result, and we can translate the particular solution into a solution of the other problem.

This isn't *quite* a complete proof, but hopefully is near enough to give you a guide.

Comment: I got this one. What would be a formal proof, would it be through induction?

Comment: You might use induction to complete the proof, yes.

Comment: what can be the structure of induction statement that I need to work on ?